# SQL get the specific row and column with NULL value

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there anyway to get only the specific row and column in your table that is null?

Sample TABLE

```
PK     COL1     COL2     COL3
1      AA       BB       CC
2               BB       CC
3      AA
```

Assume Result would be:

```
PK     AK     NewCOL   
1      2      COL1
2      3      COL2   
3      3      COL3
```

*AK is the PK of the first table.

I researched about this :
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28726/select-column-names-whose-entries-are-not-null
but sadly, it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
select PK, 'COL1' from sampleTable where COL1 IS NULL
UNION
select PK, 'COL2' from sampleTable where COL2 IS NULL
UNION
select PK, 'COL3' from sampleTable where COL3 IS NULL
```

You can wrap this around rownum to get your first column.

Answer (score 0):

Below query will returns the column names which will have null values along with pk values. this information you can copy to other table.

```
 select pk,nvl(col1,'col1') as columns_1 from table
    where col1 is null
    union all
    select pk,nvl(col2,'col2') as columns_1 from table
    where col2 is null
    union all
    select pk,nvl(col3,'col3') as columns_1 from table
    where col3 is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative to the UNION ALL methods, which may (or may not!) be quicker than reading from the same table multiple times:

```
with sample_data as (select 1 pk, 'AA' col1, 'BB' col2, 'CC' col3 from dual union all
                     select 2 pk, null col1, 'BB' col2, 'CC' col3 from dual union all
                     select 3 pk, 'AA' col1, null col2, null col3 from dual)
-- end of mimicking a table called sample_data with data in it
select row_number() over (order by sd.pk, d.id) pk, -- only for demo or reporting purposes; use a sequence.nextval for production code, if you're inserting this data somewhere.
       sd.pk ak,
       case when d.id = 1 then 'COL1'
            when d.id = 2 then 'COL2'
            when d.id = 3 then 'COL3'
       end newcol
from   sample_data sd
       inner join (select     level id
                   from       dual
                   connect by level <= 3) d on (   (sd.col1 is null and d.id = 1)
                                                or (sd.col2 is null and d.id = 2)
                                                or (sd.col3 is null and d.id = 3));

        PK         AK NEWCOL
---------- ---------- ------
         1          2 COL1  
         2          3 COL2  
         3          3 COL3
```